# Excel Highlight cells where numbers in a cell contains same digit twice or more

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a excel list with 4 digit combinations
about 10000 combination numbers like:

Here sample list:

```
0001
0002
....
1234
....
9998
9999
```

I need to highlight numbers where we have number which containts 2 same digits or 3 same digits
like in 0001 we have number 0 repeated 3 times or in 9999 we have number 9 repeated 4 times in the number

Is there way to do this (any formula) in excel to hightlight numbers like this?

Comment: Is the input text or formatted numbers to show 4 digits? Also what exactly is "repeated". Would you want to highlight `1214` aswell or only when digits are connected?

Comment: @JvdV I created the list with this formula
`=TEXT(ROW(A1)-1;"0000")`

Comment: Ok, so they are text. Thanks.

Comment: When digits are connected only, sorry i did not mention that one in my question

Comment: 8789 should not be highlighted?

Comment: No, only when its connected
like 8558 should be highlighted, or 0012 or 0122

Comment: Well a very boring solution would be just to scram the alternatives inside OR(). For example: `=OR(LEFT($A1)=MID($A1,2,1),MID($A1,2,1)=MID($A1,3,1),MID($A1,3,1)=RIGHT($A1))` where `$A1` should be changed to whatever is your starting cell in your range to be highlighted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if there is a simpler method - but this works for Excel 365:

```
=LET(dSplit,MID(A1,SEQUENCE(1,4),1), 
     dOffset,MID(A1,SEQUENCE(1,4,2),1),
     OR(dSplit=dOffset))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. For highlighting the cells (I still assume conditional formatting). `=OR(MID($A1,SEQUENCE(3),1)=MID($A1,SEQUENCE(3)+1,1))`

Comment: @JvdV - ahhh that was the simplification I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

I know this question already has an accepted answer, but I just couldn't help it:
When two digits are equal, it means that the number they compose can be divided by 11, or the number modulo 11 equals zero.

| Description | Formula |
| --- | --- |
| The first two digits of a four-digit number | `=INT(A1/100)` |
| The intermediate two digits of a four-digit number | `MOD(INT(A1/10);100)` |
| The last two digits of a four-digit number | `MOD(A1;100)` |

All combined, this generates the following formula:

```
=OR(MOD( INT(A1/100)         ; 11 )=0;
    MOD( MOD(INT(A1/10);100) ; 11 )=0;
    MOD( MOD(A1;100)         ; 11 )=0)
```

Simplified:

```
=OR(MOD(INT(A1/100);11)=0;MOD(MOD(INT(A1/10);100);11)=0;MOD(MOD(A1;100);11)=0)
```

Have fun :-)